# Load other JSON path by clicking on button with Angular 4 and Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, http-get

I have two json files. One of them contains an array of primary color objects and the other json file contains an array of secondary color objects. With two buttons I wanna switch between the two files and show their data. So I would have to change the filename of the path to show the data of the other json.

> Example:
>
> get('../../assets/data/primarycolors.json')
>
> *User clicks on button and path changes to:*
>
> get('../../assets/data/secondarycolors.json')

I'm having an Ionic 3 app with a sidemenu. The buttons are located in this sidemenu. When the user clicks on one of them, a function changeColors('name') is called.

**app.html**

```
<button (click)="changeColor('P')">Primary</button>
<button (click)="changeColor('S')">Secondary</button>
```

The function looks like this:

**app.component.ts**

```
changeColor(name) {
    this.restProvider.changeColorJson(name);
  }
```

As you can see, I was calling a function from **this.restProvider**

This is the function, where I'm changing the json file i want to get.

**rest.ts**

```
jsonFile = 'primarycolors.json';
.
.
.
changeColorJson(name) {
if(name === 'S'){
  this.jsonFile = 'secondarycolors.json';
  this.getDataFromJson();
}
else {
  this.jsonFile = 'primarycolors.json';
  this.getDataFromJson();
}
}


getDataFromJson() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('../../assets/data/' + this.jsonFile) //here should be the path with the correct file
        .subscribe((data) => {
          resolve(data);
          console.log(data);
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

And last but not least, the html and typescript file, where i'm displaying the color names. In this Typescript file I also call the getDataFromJson() function, which you can see above.

**colors.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let color of colors">
  <p>{{color.name}}</p>
</div>
```

**colors.ts**

```
colors: any;
.
.
.

  getData() {
    this.restProvider.getDataFromJson() //the same function from above
      .then(data => {
        this.colors = data; //adding the data I got from json to colors
   });
  }
```

Now to my problem:
As you can see, I set the variable jsonFile (in rest.ts) to 'primarycolors.json' first, because I want the default to be primary colors. So this works and the primary colors are shown, but when I click on the button to show the secondary colors, nothing changes. I think reason for this might be, because I'm also calling getDataFromJson() in colors.ts and then it won't refresh and show the new data.

So basically my question is, how do I have to change my code, so I can switch between the two files and show the correct data?

Answer (score 0):

There are two point in your Question

Firstly, Please check whether you method getting correct parameter value and also verify that your method from app.component.ts is called again after getting default value.

Secondly, In your question when you click on the button it might take data from your required json file. But might not properly assigned to you object

```
 this.colors = data;
```

you must verify after getting data by making HttpGet call it should I assign to your required object.It looks like you are not assigning json value to you object.

Comment: I checked it and my method should get the correct parameter value. My method from app.component.ts is also called again.

For your second question, with a console.log i checked what's in colors, and yes the data is assigned correctly to it.

Comment: If values are assigned correctly then your html should be re-rendered to change it. Its look line your html once generated with default values after then it is not being re-rendered.

Comment: ya i also think that this could be the problem, but i dont know how to change my code to fix this. Any recommendations?

Comment: Try to call this method **getDataFromJson** from `color.ts` file. as it is render in you color.html file. if it work then good else you have to variable change event which help you to re-rendered 
An other solution is to add refresh method which only refresh your color component only

Comment: I'm not sure if I exactly understand what you mean, but I'm already calling getDataFromJson() in `color.ts`. I'm calling it in the getData() function. And then I'm assigning the result of getDataFromJson() to colors. But, ya i'm having a look at the other solutions you mentioned.